# Remove unused makeStyles properties

Tags: material-ui

I am working in a codebase where over time, we have done many changes to our pages and components thus resulting in a lot of styles that are now not being used. We would like to clean up our codebase and remove any unused makeStyles properties.

Our styles are being imported from a separate file. For example:

## container.styles.ts

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    ...
  },
  oldContainerStyle1: { ... },
  oldContainerStyle2: { ... },
  oldContainerStyle3: { ... },
  oldComponentStyle1: { ... },
  ...
  },
});
```

## container.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from "react";

import { useStyles } from "./container.styles";


interface IProps {
  ...
}

export const AutoCompleteContainer: FC<IProps> = ({...}) => {
   const classes = useStyles();
   return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
      ...
   )


}
```

We are using tslint and have looked into seeing if it is possible but we still cannot seem to find an answer on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this dependency  https://github.com/jens-ox/eslint-plugin-material-ui-unused-classes

not sure for tslint.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: Your answer was the most useful for me so far. Unfortunately with this plugin, it cannot detect unused makeStyles in a separate file which is the style within the codebase. Detecting unused makeStyles may not be possible if the files are separate.